# Get the generator function's name from a generator

Tags: javascript, generator, iterable

In Javascript, given a generator object, how do I get it to output the name of the generator function that returned back that generator object?

In other words:

```js
function* thisIsMyName(i) {
  yield i;
}

const gen = thisIsMyName(10);

console.log(gen.name); // How do I get this to output "thisIsMyName" using only the gen object?
```

Calling `gen.name` doesn't work as it isn't a [function](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/name) but a [generator object](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Generator)

Comment: Just out of curiosity, what's the reason of needing to know the generator function's `name`. The OP at least must have access to the generator function as reference. Otherwise there is no chance of invoking it. Or is it just the generator the OP is dealing with? And in the latter case, why then does the OP need to know the generator function's `name`? (I suppose the OP can neither access nor change the script/source where the generator function got implemented.)

Comment: Why would you expect this to work? A return value from a function never implicitly carries any reference to the function that returned it. You would need to create an intermediate factory that passed a reference to the function as well as the returned generator object.

Comment: @PeterSeliger The use case is a function that takes in a generator object and does things with it, including logging. This function is called in multiple places, and it's useful to be able to log what generator function this generator object belongs to. I could change the script source, but that's added code that I was hoping to not need.

Comment: @pilchard when you put it that way it makes sense. I guess I was hoping for this because I am not the one creating or returning the generator object, something else is.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I am afraid you cannot access it like that because the reference to the function that generated this generator is stored in a property defined by a symbol. Symbols are unique and cannot be recreated (but nut all the time, see `Symbol.for`). Meaning that if you don't have the reference to a symbol you cannot get its value.

`Object.getOwnPropertySymbols()` does not return the native ones.

You can see however the symbol props in the console when inspecting the instance:

[image: Console]

You can solve this however with a wrapper function, meaning a function that will return both the generator and the generator function:

```
function thisIsMyName(value){
  const generatorFunction = function* thisIsMyName(i) {
    yield i;
  }
  return {
    generator : generatorFunction(value),
    generatorFunction: generatorFunction
  }
}
const gen = thisIsMyName(10);

console.log(gen.generatorFunction.name) // prints thisIsMyName
console.log(gen.generator.next()) // prints {value: 10, done: false}
```

Comment: I still think, the only reason the OP is asking this Q. is that the OP has no access to the script. Thus the OP can not use such a wrapper approach. And upvote for the explanation of the Symbol based slot(s).

Comment: Sometimes there are questions that cannot be answered with a `YES you can do it` :) , and that is OKAY I guess

Comment: @PeterSeliger That would make more sense :) but this wasn't the use case here. I can make changes to the script, but I was hoping to not add boilerplate code and was hoping it would just be available, like many other handy things in Javascript.

Comment: @TiberiuC. yes I was perfectly happy with a "this cannot be done" response here. Just wanted to make sure this cannot be done as my existing research into it was seeming that way and maybe I missed something!

Answer (score 0):

From the comments:

> You would need to create an intermediate factory that passed a reference to the function as well as the returned generator object

Not really usefull, but it may be something like:

```js
const someGenerator = {
  *thisIsMyName(i = 1, limit = 10) {
    while (i < limit) {
      yield i++;
    }
  },
  get name() {return this.thisIsMyName.name},
};

const myGen = { name: someGenerator.name, i: someGenerator.thisIsMyName(15, 20)};
console.log(myGen.i.next().value, myGen.name);
```

Or ...

```js
function createGenerator(name, min = 1, max = 10) {
  function* xGen() {
    while (min < max) {
      yield min++;
    }
  };
  
  return {gen: xGen(), name,};
};

const myGen = createGenerator(`myName`, 15, 20);
const values = [];
let nxt = {};
while (!nxt.done) {
  nxt = myGen.gen.next();
  !nxt.done && values.push(nxt.value);
}
console.log(values.join(`, `), `\nmyGen.name = '${myGen.name}'`);
```